# Why can't KeyAdapter understand shift +1 =?

Tags: java, key

To a computer:

```
int key = e.getKeyCode();
if(e.getKeyCode() == VK_Shift && e.getKeyCode() == VK_1){
text = "!";
}
```

Does nothing, but to me it should set it to an exclamation mark. Why won't this work? I am trying to make a game and in the chat box, I need text to be set to an exclamation mark when the user does Shift 1.

Comment: And what events are you reacting to?

Answer (score 1):

> Why won't this work?

You're asking whether a single value (`e.getKeyCode()`) is equal to both `VK_Shift` and `VK_1`. Unless those two have the same value (which they don't) the `if` condition can *never* be satisfied.

The documentation makes this pretty clear:

> Virtual key codes are used to report which keyboard key has been pressed, rather than a character generated by the combination of one or more keystrokes (such as "A", which comes from shift and "a").
>
> For example, pressing the Shift key will cause a KEY_PRESSED event with a VK_SHIFT keyCode, while pressing the 'a' key will result in a VK_A keyCode. After the 'a' key is released, a KEY_RELEASED event will be fired with VK_A. Separately, a KEY_TYPED event with a keyChar value of 'A' is generated.

So in other words, you'd need to handle *two* `KEY_PRESSED` events, remembering the first one (shift) as context for the second (1).

Perhaps you should be looking for `KEY_TYPED` events (using `KeyAdapter.keyTyped()`) and using `e.getKeyChar()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that is so much better though, when I press shift, I get an ugly box: http://prntscr.com/3ihgn3

Comment: @user3625168: Well we haven't got nearly enough information to know why that's happening, but it sounds like a different problem. You should separate "Can I detect the user typing Shift-1?" from "Can I do the right thing when I detect it?"

Comment: @user3625168: You've missed my point: this should be in a separate question, ideally with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Address one issue per question. (It's not clear why you're using `e.getKeyChar()` in `keyReleased` at all, to be honest. I'd stick with `keyTyped`.)